# How do I get fingerprint gestures on an Android phone such as the Pixel?

Tags: java, android

I am making an app for my own use (might publish it later, but for now it is just for me), and it is going to add more gestures to the finger print scanner (currently, if the option is enabled, if you swipe down on the fingerprint scanner, it opens up your notifications). I don't think it is native to the Android SDK. Are there any libraries on it or anything?

Comment: I do not think that this is exposed to developers in any conventional fashion. And, for security reasons, anything involving the fingerprint sensor is going to be locked down pretty tight. Are you running on a rooted device and are looking to use that to try to get to low-level hardware events that are not normally exposed?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am very new to Android, so I don't know if I need to root it to do this, but I want to just add more gestures. Some examples would include swiping right to close current app, swiping left for undo, tapping it to go home, holding it (or double tapping it, not yet sure) to open the app switcher, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you check this link, What is this about https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/FingerprintGestureController

Comment: @livemaker: That came out last year and it covers some of what the OP is seeking. It's tied to accessibility, though, and Google has at times cracked down on apps using accessibility APIs for reasons other than accessibility. As I [wrote about last year](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/20/accessibilityservice-bans.html), limiting fingerprint gestures to accessibility apps was disappointing choice IMHO.

Comment: thanks for your time @CommonsWare red through your blog, it's a hard choice for developers to work on gestures.